# Windows 7 boot manager issue

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, bootloader, opensuse, bootmgr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Reinstalling” the Windows 7 boot manager](https://superuser.com/questions/99162/reinstalling-the-windows-7-boot-manager)

I was having windows 7 installed on my laptop, yesterday I tried to install **Open Suse** operating system. During its installation I chose a `NTFS` partition and formatted it to `ext4` filesystem. During installation an error came that **mount point cannot be created on this partition** and I aborted the installation. They on reboot a message came **BootMgr is missing**. I then reinstalled the windows but on complete installation when setup rebooted the system then a blank screen came with a cursor blinking. I went through many forums and learnt may startup repairs and commands but it continues to hang up at a blank screen with cursor blinking. Reinstalling new windows 7 is also not doing any effect. I urgently need to repair my laptop for very important work. Please Help

Comment: You could try to wipe out MBR and _any hidden data_ before first partition: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd? bs=512 count=2048` and then try installation again. **Change `/dev/sd?` as required**, for example _`/dev/sda`_ should be first harddisk. At least if it is Lenovo...

Answer (score 0):

Download a Live CD of linux of your choice, make a bootable usb flash drive with LiveUSB creator and try to boot from usb device. If it fails to boot then burn the CD image and try to boot from CD. Then you have access to your disk and you can try to find out what is going on with it.