# My hp ProBook 4540s is stuck in hp logo

Tags: windows-7, boot, bootloader, ubuntu-14.04

I was trying to delete Ubuntu 14.0.4 system from my laptop using windows 7. So I ran Windows 7 and i opened disk management and i deleted a disk that has the size of 58 GB wich is supposed to include the ubuntu system and another one with 3 GB (not named). When i restarted the laptop it stuck in HP logo on boot loader.

when i pressed Esc botton i get the following options:

<kbd>F1</kbd> System Information

<kbd>F2</kbd> System Diagnostics

<kbd>F7</kbd> HP SpareKey

<kbd>F9</kbd> Boot Device Options

<kbd>F10</kbd> BIOS Setup

<kbd>F12</kbd> Network Boot

<kbd>ENTER</kbd>-Continue Startup

pleas help me

Comment: Press f2 and get some more info.... Why did you delete the disk instead of formatting ? You clearly deleted your boot partition also.

Comment: when i press f2 it shows up 4 options: memory test, hard disk check, language, exit

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/99162/reinstalling-the-windows-7-boot-manager

Comment: i will try it and tell you what happened